# How to import only functions in a script with custom package/module in Python?

Tags: python, object, import, module, package

I'm building a package and a noticed that when I import the submodules, they include all of the built-ins that I've imported as well.  Is there a way to get around this so when I navigate the submodule with tab complete only the functions and objects from the script are present?

For example, when I import `examplemodule.submodule` to only see `function_i_want` when I'm navigating the package contents?

#### Directory structure

```
examplemodule
    | __init__.py
    | submodule
         | __init__.py
         | submodule.py
```

#### examplemodule | submodule | submodule.py

```
from collections import *
def function_i_want():
    return True
```

Here's an example of what I can import from the module:

```
>>> import examplemodule
>>> from examplemodule import submodule
>>> submodule.
submodule.AsyncGenerator(   submodule.MappingView(
submodule.AsyncIterable(    submodule.MutableMapping(
submodule.AsyncIterator(    submodule.MutableSequence(
submodule.Awaitable(        submodule.MutableSet(
submodule.ByteString(       submodule.OrderedDict(
submodule.Callable(         submodule.Reversible(
submodule.ChainMap(         submodule.Sequence(
submodule.Collection(       submodule.Set(
submodule.Container(        submodule.Sized(
submodule.Coroutine(        submodule.UserDict(
submodule.Counter(          submodule.UserList(
submodule.Generator(        submodule.UserString(
submodule.Hashable(         submodule.ValuesView(
submodule.ItemsView(        submodule.defaultdict(
submodule.Iterable(         submodule.deque(
submodule.Iterator(         submodule.function_i_want(
submodule.KeysView(         submodule.namedtuple(
submodule.Mapping(          submodule.submodule
```

Comment: what's wrong with `from examplemodule.submodule import function_i_want`?

Comment: The real examples get a little more complicated but yea this should be ok.  Is this the only way that doesn't include showing everything? I will just need to make sure to update it after adding new features

Answer (score 2):

When you say `from x.y import *` you are [importing everything defined in `__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) from the module `y` that resides in directory `x`.

If you'd only like to `import` a subset of `y` you can do the following:

1. Limit what you're importing from your script

```
from examplemodule.submodule import function_i_want
```

or

```
from examplemodule.submodule import (
    function_i_want,
    other_function_i_want
)
```

2. Define `__all__` in your `__init__.py`

```
__all__ = ['function_i_want', 'other_function_i_want']
```

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is import just the module e.g.
    import examplemodule
    examplemodule.submodule
what this does is only calls the function if you write the module first then .submodule.  this is also good if you have more than one module